# How to Implement Socket Connection

Tags: iphone, sockets

"How to implement Socket connection in my application."

If anybody have some related code please give me the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this very comprehensive tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) on Ray Wenderlich's incredible site dealing with sockets specifically on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't developed anything using sockets on the iPhone specifically, but for BSD sockets, [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) is pretty incredible. Hopefully that's helpful and the iPhone APIs are similar.